# CentOS7 emacs installation error: No X toolkit could be found

Tags: centos, emacs

When running:

`sudo ./configure`

I got error:

`checking for libXaw... configure: error: No X toolkit could be found.
If you are sure you want Emacs compiled without an X toolkit, pass
  --with-x-toolkit=no
to configure.  Otherwise, install the development libraries for the toolkit
that you want to use (e.g. Gtk+) and re-run configure.`

According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506906/compile-error-checking-for-libxaw-configure-error-no-x-toolkit-could-be-fo), I ran the following command to install X toolkit:

`sudo yum install build-essential texinfo libx11-dev libxpm-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libgtk2.0-dev libncurses-dev libxpm-dev automake autoconf`

However, when I run configure, I get the same error. How do I successfully resolve the dependency error and install emacs?

Comment: Are you sure you need to run `./configure` with `sudo`?  What happens if you run it as yourself?

Answer (score 5):

Those development packages are for the Debian/Ubuntu/Mint family which is why they end in `dev`.

The development packages that you are looking for are `libpng-devel libtiff-devel openjpeg-devel gtk2-devel ncurses-devel giflib-devel libX11-devel libXpm-devel`. The development packages end in `devel` for the Fedora/RHEL/CentOS family.

As you have `sudo`, you can also just `yum install emacs` which is a lot easier.